# How to get the throughput in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ip, bandwidth

Hello I want to calculate the throughput through C# using `HttpWebRequest`.
I thought of requesting a big file (500KB) while running a `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`.

Then I could calculate the KB/s rate. I have 2 problems at this point:
1. How accurate is this going to be? Can I rely on it or should I just use another method?

2. How can I host the file on a URL I can hard-code without worrying about server-side problems? Could I somehow use a file with such a size already present preferably on googles or microsofts page?

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: If you are downloading a file hosted by someone else, make sure that you are not violating their terms of service (TOS) by doing so.

Comment: I wish people would use the less confusing term throughput rather than bandwidth.

Comment: @Greg Thank you for that, I would've forgotten about that :D

Comment: @ChaosPandion what exactly is the difference? Everybody knows what I'm talking about.

Comment: @alex - To those with an electronics background the definition is literal. Bandwidth is the range of frequencies supported on a given band. Throughput is the amount that can be processed by a system over time.

Comment: Ah ok I did'nt know that. I'll edit..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's really not something you should rely on:

- Your user's bandwidth is going to fluctuate depending on the time of day, how busy their ISP is, what other programs they have open using the connection...
- As well as that, if you're doing this based on a file hosted on a server, the result you get will depend on how busy that server is.
- If one of your users has a limit on how much data they can download, they might not thank you for making them download an extra file that they don't need.

You'd be best asking your user to pick their connection type from a list (e.g. "Modem - 56kbps", "DSL - < 2Mbps"), and use that to estimate how much bandwidth you'll have available.

Comment: The project I'm working on is really internet based. There is no way anybody could think about using it if he/she has no DSL.

Comment: Well, ask them whether they have 512kbps, 1Mbps, 2Mbps... Lots of programs (Steam, iTunes...) do this to work out how much bandwidth they can get at.

Comment: I dont think I should bother the user with that. My program should run "on its own" and I dont think that 500KB will harm anybody. Even with DSL Lite.

Comment: the problem is that 500KB is way too small to get an accurate measurement.

Comment: ah now I understand. Do you think it would be possible to download the file multiple times, like download it 10 times and see, if it takes too long than abort it and use the measured 5 times?

Comment: And what if their PC starts downloading updates halfway through the 3rd attempt, so their connection is suddenly slower? Or if you work out the throughput at 3am, and then use the same value at 11am when the network is much busier?  What if they're using a mobile dongle and paying for their internet connection by the megabyte?